# parsing foursquare's json data

Tags: json, decode

I need to parse this json data and get User list (under response->herenow->items->0->user)

Data:

{"meta":{"code":200,"requestId":"5906f571db04f52e8797b50f"},"notifications":[{"type":"notificationTray","item":{"unreadCount":0}}],"response":{"hereNow":{"count":1,"items":[{"id":"5906f56e419a9e5f95c08f46","createdAt":1493628270,"type":"checkin","entities":[],"shout":"(test)","timeZoneOffset":180,"user":{"id":"xxx","firstName":"xxx","lastName":"xxx","gender":"male","relationship":"self","photo":{"prefix":"https://igx.4sqi.net/img/user/","suffix":"/31705596-L5PSQVI2PQOH2ZSR.jpg"}},"likes":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"like":false}]}}}

It works until items part. After this [0] thing I couldn't parse anything.

```
$venues = json_decode($response, true);
$data_get = $venues[response][hereNow][items];
```

What I am missing?

Comment: try $data_get_id = $venues['response']['hereNow']['items'][0]['user']['id'] , its working

Comment: no it is not working in this way.